# Dynamically change editTexts position based on screen Size / DPI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, geolocation, android-windowmanager

I would like to change the position of one element (editText) in my UI when the user taps it. The positioning should be ~20 dp under the actionBar, no matter screen-size or DPI the device is using.

How do I accomplish this using only (java)code? Please try to give a more exact answer. I have seen other examples similar to this but none that explains an exakt scenario? I was thinking of a start like the code below? Then what?:

```
  DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
  mSearchField = (EditText)v.findViewById (R.id.something);

  getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            int [] loc = new int[2];
            mSearchField.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
            int distance = dm.heightPixels - loc[1];
```

Comment: Can you post your xml layout, or explain how your views are set up on screen? Maybe you don't need to get the display dimensions to achieve what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Get the Display height and width using DisplayMetrics.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        mContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        Log.e("width",width+""+height);
```